# Can I test for support of javascript addRule to switch between addRule/insertRule?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, methods

I need to use `insertRule` to modify some CSS via Javascript. I also need to support IE7-8, so I need some way to differentiate in Javascript whether I should use `insertRule` or `addRule` (without browser sniffing).

This is what I'm trying and it does not work:

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets   
if(sheets.insertRule) {
    alert("insert");
    // insert 
} else {
    alert("add");
    // add
}
```

Any idea if this is possible and how to get it to work?

**EDIT:**
If I run this in IE8, I get an error on the page `object does not support this property or method`

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: IE8 complains there is an error on the page. If I leave out this script, no errors on the page. Thx. Edited. my question

Comment: ok. Answer was correct. Please add it back, so I can check it.

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/4jPP5/show/` No bugs in IE8.

Comment: yah. I did not comment out my initial `insertRule`... that's why the error still showed up and addRule wasn't alerting. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be no bugs in IE8, as evidenced by [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4jPP5/show/) test run.

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets   
if(sheets.insertRule) {
    alert("insert");
    // insert
} else {
    alert("add");
    // add
}
```

The problem is probably due to the fact that the code you have replaced with comments calls methods that are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following on Firefox and it worked, giving me insertRule only. You need to specify which stylesheet to use.

Hope this is helpful for those who need it.

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets[0];   

if (sheets.addRule) {
    alert("addRule");
}

if (sheets.insertRule) {
    alert("insertRule");
}
```